# Not able to iterate through SPTPlaylistList items

Tags: swift, sdk, spotify

I am trying to access all the playlists of a Spotify user

```
 let request2: URLRequest = try! SPTPlaylistList.createRequestForGettingPlaylists(forUser: self.username, withAccessToken: accessToken)
    print(request2)
    SPTRequest.sharedHandler().perform(request2) { (error, response, data) in
        if error == nil {
            print(response)
            let playlists = try! SPTPlaylistList(from: data, with: response)
}else{
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

And I can see the playlists if I print 'playlists'

```
some([<SPTPartialPlaylist: 0x10aa854d0>: john mayer [2 tracks] (spotify:user:virajdeshpande88:playlist:3BLBrqb3CURu5KFPqdYqd1), <SPTPartialPlaylist: 0x10aa922a0>: beatles [2 tracks] (spotify:user:virajdeshpande88:playlist:2t6z8KEhZGzY7Tqvy8QoW4)])
```

But I can't access the playlists individually or iterate through playlists.items. If I do the following:

```
print (playlists.items[0])
```

I get 'Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'.

Update: I tried using playlistsForUser:withAccessToken:callback: and I am able to access all the user's playlists now. But it only seems to work if the following block of code is inside the if {} block of the piece of code I posted above. If this block is placed just by itself, I get the nil value error again.

```
    SPTPlaylistList.playlists(forUser: self.username, withAccessToken: accessToken, callback: {(error, playlist_list)  in
    if error == nil {
        let list = playlist_list as! SPTPlaylistList
        print(list.items[0])
        print(list.items[1])
        let playlist = list.items[0] as! SPTPartialPlaylist
        print(playlist.name)
    }else{
        print("latest error")
       }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using force unwrap `!`.

```
    if let request2: URLRequest = try? SPTPlaylistList.createRequestForGettingPlaylists(forUser: self.username, withAccessToken: accessToken){
        print(request2)
        SPTRequest.sharedHandler().perform(request2) { (error, response, data) in
            if error == nil {
                print(response)
                if let playlists = try? SPTPlaylistList(from: data, with: response) {
                    playlists.forEach{ playlist in
                        print(playlist)
                        // do thing with your each playlist
                    }
                }
            }else{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```